# Cannot get onClickButton in custom adapter to respond correctly?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am trying to have the button's text change on a button click in the list view, and I tried doing it through the custom adapter. With logs the onclick is called just the text does not seem to change:

This is my adapter code:

```
public class UserViewerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public List<DatabaseUser> _list;
    public List<UserResponse> _listForSearch;
    private final Activity mContext;
    private ConfirmManager confirmManager;
    private int query;
    private Button isFriend;
    // database helper
    private DatabaseHelper db;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public UserViewerAdapter(Activity context, List<DatabaseUser> list) {
        mContext = context;
        _list = list;
        //establishing db
        db = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        confirmManager = new ConfirmManager();
        query = 0;

    }

    public UserViewerAdapter( List<UserResponse> list, Activity context) {
        mContext = context;
        _listForSearch = list;
        query = 1;
        //establishing db
        db = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        confirmManager = new ConfirmManager();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(query == 0) {
            return _list.size();
        }
        return _listForSearch.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        if(query == 0) {
            return _list.get(position);
        }
        return _listForSearch.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.users_layout, null);


        }


        ImageView userImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);
         isFriend = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnFriend);

        String isFriendText;


        //coming from search
        if(query == 1) {
            if (_listForSearch != null && _listForSearch.size() > 0) {
                text.setText(_listForSearch.get(position).getName());
            }

            Picasso.with(mContext).setLoggingEnabled(true);

//        String pictureToAdd = Constants.USER_IMAGES + _listForSearch.get(position).getPicId();
//        String photo = _listForSearch.get(position).get_picture();
//        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "THE photo IS " + photo);
//        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "THE constant IS " + Constants.USER_IMAGES);

//        if (photo.equals("default.jpg")) {
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.default_profile_image).resize(50, 50).into(userImage);

            isFriendText = "Add Friend";
            if(_listForSearch.get(position).isFriend()) {

                isFriendText = "Remove Friend";
            }
            isFriend.setText(isFriendText);


            final String finalIsFriendText = isFriendText;
            isFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //Remove friend
                    callConfirmAddOrRemove(_listForSearch.get(position), finalIsFriendText);

                    Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "clicked friend button " + finalIsFriendText);

                }
            });
        }



        return v;
    }

    private void changeText(String finalIsFriendText) {
        String newTextToFill = "";
        if(finalIsFriendText.equals("Remove Friend")) {
            newTextToFill = "Add Friend";
        }
        if(finalIsFriendText.equals("Add Friend")) {
            newTextToFill = "Remove Friend";
        }

        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "changing text of friend button " + newTextToFill);

        isFriend.setText(newTextToFill);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    private void callConfirmAddOrRemove(UserResponse userResponse, String finalIsFriendText) {

        boolean dlg = confirmManager.Confirm(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.remove_friend), mContext.getString(R.string.details_confirmation)
                        + "\n" + mContext.getString(R.string.details_info),
                mContext.getString(R.string.submit), mContext.getString(R.string.cancel), addOrRemove(userResponse, finalIsFriendText),
                cancelPost());

    }

    private Runnable addOrRemove(final UserResponse userResponse, final String finalIsFriendText) {
        return new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                sendToDb(userResponse, finalIsFriendText);

            }

        };
    }

    private void sendToDb(UserResponse userResponse, String finalIsFriendText) {


        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "sending to db friend change");
        String uid, name, picid;
        int points, totalshifts, totalhours, isguarding, isfriend;
            uid = userResponse.getUserId();
            name = userResponse.getName();
            picid = userResponse.getPictureId();
            points = userResponse.getTotalPoints();
            totalshifts = userResponse.getTotalShifts();
            totalhours = userResponse.getTotalHours();
            isguarding = 0;
            if(userResponse.isCheckedIn()) {
                isguarding = 1;
            }

            //have to do the opposite since trying to add or remove 3 means newly added friend, 2 means newly removed friend
            isfriend = 3;

            if(userResponse.isFriend()) {
                isfriend = 2;
            }


        DatabaseUser addOrRemoveUser = new DatabaseUser(uid, name, picid, points, totalshifts,totalhours, isguarding, isfriend);

        db.updateFriend(addOrRemoveUser);
        changeText(finalIsFriendText);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    private Runnable cancelPost() {
        return new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "Canceled posting item");
            }
        };
    }




}
```

This is the xml (I set android focusable to false for the listview on itemclick to work):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >
    <!--  ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userImage"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Name-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="DEFAULT NAME"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>


    <!-- Friend button -->
   <Button android:id="@+id/btnFriend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/friends"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="15dip"
       android:focusable="false"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the click listener of `getView`, the method:

```
callConfirmAddOrRemove(_listForSearch.get(position), finalIsFriendText);
```

you could not get right `position`, so you have to define a final `position`, or binding a `position` tag with the button `isFriend`.

[**UPDATE**]

```
isFriend.setTag(position); //this is inside getView
```

and then in your listener:

```
int position = (int)v.getTag(); //this position will be correct one
```

Hope this help!

Comment: How do I go about this method?

Comment: I am confused in the onClickListener what do I do with the position value though?

Comment: check my update, this `position` is one of button what you click. you can not just use the position of `getView`

Comment: Cast to int should be ok based on Java autoboxing, because obviously the tag is Integer object. It did not work for you? maybe you are using JDK less than 7

Comment: Actually originally I used Integer, no problem I can change it back, but no need you refuse the answer

Comment: Sorry about that didn't realized i unchecked it when going to edit

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the text in a separate thread, however, only the **UI Main Thread** can change Views like TextViews and Buttons.

To work it out, you can use `runOnUiThread`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Update Button Text
    }
});
```

So, in `sendToDB`, change

```
changeText(finalIsFriendText);
```

for

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        changeText(finalIsFriendText);
    }
});
```

`runOnUIThread` is a method from java.lang.Runnable as can be seen in the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

> Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is
>   the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current
>   thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue
>   of the UI thread.

So it is a function that takes the Runnable you input as parameter, and run it in the UI Thread, making it possible to change UI elements inside any other threads.

Comment: What is runOnUiThread is that the name of the method? and you need a return value for Runnable

Comment: I just tried your method and it still does not change the value of the text, it logs the new current text that needs to be changed but nothing gets set

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `isFriend` being used to update text, use another to do this operation.

And also notice the *UI Main Thread* problem.

```
private Button btnToUpdate;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    btnToUpdate = v; //save which button to update
    //Remove friend
    callConfirmAddOrRemove(_listForSearch.get(position), finalIsFriendText);

    Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "clicked friend button " + finalIsFriendText);

}

private void changeText(String finalIsFriendText) {
    String newTextToFill = "";
    if(finalIsFriendText.equals("Remove Friend")) {
        newTextToFill = "Add Friend";
    }
    if(finalIsFriendText.equals("Add Friend")) {
        newTextToFill = "Remove Friend";
    }

    Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "changing text of friend button " + newTextToFill);

    btnToUpdate.setText(newTextToFill); //use btnToUpdate to update text
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```